# Привязка endpoint к IPv6 или глобальному ip-адрессу в WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

Здравствуйте, изучаю WCF. Я протестил пример который был дан в книге все работает, но там была привязка к адресу "http:\localhost:8080\MagicEightBallService", но я бы хотел привязываться не к локальному хосту, а, например, к адресу IPv6 или же глобальному IP(тот который указывает 2ip.ru). В случае с IPv6 не выходит привязать(выдает исключение), а в случае когда привязываю хост к "http:\<глобальный IP>:8080\MagicEightBallService" то хост запускается, но я не могу добавить ссылку на сервис используя этот адрес, его просто не находит. Дело в том, что я бы хотел, чтобы клиент был на другом компе и обращался по этому адресу к сервису. Когда работал с классом Socket, там было просто, я задавал IPv6 на клиенте и сервере и спокойно клиент мог работать с сервером на разных машинах, а тут не выходит. Помогите разобраться как это делается правильно в WCF. Кстати по адресу http://IP:8080/MagicEightBallService перейти не могу, странно, по идее сервис запущен

Comment: Ну я канеш могу указать IPv4 адресс, но с каждым перезапуском компа меняется, из-за этого я и указывал постоянно IPv6.

Comment: В общем IPv6 просто указывать нужно было в квадратных скобках, но вопрос возник другой, чего же не работает на разных машинах, фаерволла разшение есть, все есть, в общем думаю дальше